# Sync a SQLLiteDB from an Android-App with a HSQLDB from a webapplication?

Tags: android, sqlite, web-applications, synchronization, hsqldb

I'm currently working on an app that stores data in an internal SQLLiteDB and a webapplication that stores data in an internal HSQLDB and I'm lookin for an easy way to keep them in sync.

I'm using two databases because the app needs to also work offline, so that I can still access the data from the database without beeing connected to the webapplication and visa versa.